# Select query for root of the structure

Tags: php, mysql

I have a SQL table having structure as below

```
MENU1
    M1_SM_1
        M1_SM1_SSM_1
        M1_SM1_SSM_2

    M1_SM_2
        M1_SM2_SSM_1
        M1_SM2_SSM_2

    M1_SM_3
        M1_SM3_SSM_1
        M1_SM3_SSM_2

MENU2
    M2_SM_1
        M2_SM1_SSM_1
        M2_SM1_SSM_2

    M2_SM_2
        M2_SM2_SSM_1
        M2_SM2_SSM_2

........................
........................
```

All these are stored in a sql table as below

```
+ID-------NAME------PARENT_ID
 1        MENU1         0
 2        MENU2         0
 3        MENU3         0
 4        M1_SM1        1
 5        M1_SM2        1
 6        M1_SM1_SSM1   4        
 7        M1_SM1_SSM2   4        

 ............................. 
 .............................
```

Now I have given I single value may be MENU1 or M1_SM1 or M1_SM1_SSM1 (names)
(names are unique)

and i want to select its root element having parent is 0
what should be the sql query for that?

that is for example if i had given M1_SM1_SSM1 OR M1_SM1 OR MENU1 
then the selected row would be

```
+ID-------NAME------PARENT_ID
 1        MENU1         0
```

Is there any simple PHP solution using some while loops and conditions to get there?

I am new to SQL dosn't know about JOIN queries and this may be a very simple question but didn't get any solution.
Any solution is appreciated .

Comment: Can the hierarchy be more than 2 levels ? or you are looking to get just the parent information for a particular level ?

Comment: This kind of thing gets sticky very quickly. I've solved this before using nested sets: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nested_set_model

Comment: @AbhikChakraborty yes hierarchy is of fixed level as given `MENU>SUB_MENU>SUB_SUB_MENU`
and I am looking for toppest level of an element given which can MENU1,or MENU, ......

Comment: As has been mentioned, the 'nested sets' method is quickest for this. There are in open source implementation of: [Zebra_Mptt, a PHP class providing the modified preorder tree traversal algorithm](http://stefangabos.ro/php-libraries/zebra-mptt/#how-to-use)

Answer (score 0):

Try to call a variable with all coincidence like this:

```
$call = array(
"MENU1"=>array(
    "MENU1",
    "M1_SM1",
    "M1_SM1_SSM1"
),
"MENU2"=>array(
    "MENU2",
    "M1_SM2",
    "M1_SM1_SSM2"
),
"M1_SM1"=>array(
    "M1_SM1"
),
"M1_SM1_SSM1"=>array(
    "M1_SM1_SSM1"
),
"M1_SM2"=>array(
    "M1_SM2"
),
"M1_SM1_SSM2"=>array(
    "M1_SM1_SSM2"
)    
);
```

and do your query

```
foreach($call as $k=>$v){
// my select here WHERE NAME = $call[$k]

}
```

hope this what you lookin for

Comment: this process is complex and little bit time consuming also

Comment: in my case I could test this, so I'm going to wait a good and effective response.